# Obtener las números mayores de una base de datos Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

La base de datos tiene un registro diario desde 1950 hasta 2015, y necesito obtener el valor mas alto de precipitación de nada mes de 2 años en particular.

[image: La base de datos]

Usé pandas para extraer los años pero no sé cómo extraer los mayores valores de cada mes.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Pedro. Deberías agregar algo más de información, como el código que usas para leer el Excel (supongo que lo es por la captura) y seria muy bueno si pudieras aportar un ejemplo mínimo de este archivo que no sea una imagen para facilitar la reproducción del problema. La forma de abordarlo es seleccionar las filas con los años adecuados `df[(df[anio] == 1960) | (df[anio] == 2000])]`, luego usar `df.groupby` agrupando por la columna `mes` y usar `Precipitacion,max` sobre cada grupo.

Answer (score 1):

Al no contar datos voy a armar un ejemplo de prueba:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA=StringIO("""Mes;Dia;Anio;Precipitacion
    1;1;1950;1
    1;2;1950;2
    2;1;1950;3
    2;2;1950;4
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")

g = df.groupby(["Anio", "Mes"], as_index=False)[["Precipitacion"]].sum()
print(g)
```

La salida final sería:

```
   Anio  Mes  Precipitacion
0  1950    1              2
1  1950    2              4
```

La solución pasa por agrupar mediante [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) y usar la función de agregación [`max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html#pandas-dataframe-max) sobre la columna `Precipitacion`